# Cannot retrieve a color from colors.xml through a custom resource?

Tags: java, android

I'm going through an Android tutorial and I'm trying to access a color I've defined in colors.xml

```
<color name = "my_background">#3500ffff</color>
```

Then I'm trying to access this color by name:

```
Paint background = new Paint();
background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_background));
```

but it doesn't recognize my_background as a resource.  If I let the suggestions come up, only a bunch of pre-defined colors pop up that are unrelated.  Any ideas?  It doesn't make sense for me, I see almost the exact same thing from the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) and [another site](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html), but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, which version?

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse, Helios.

Comment: I should also note that I CAN access the color resource from an XML layout file.  Just not through Java for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that the problem was an`import android.R` somehow made it's way into the top of my code without me noticing.  I removed that and the problem was solved.

Comment: Yes, still right. I deleted it and imported whatever android studio suggested, and it worked.